# ошибка в input - meneger в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
 if (Input.GetButtonDown("w"))
    {
        gb.transform.position = Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
    };

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("s"))
    {
        gb.transform.position = -Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
    };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выдает ошибку:

> ArgumentException: Input Button w is not setup.  To change the input
>   settings use: Edit -> Project Settings -> Input CubeScript.Update ()
>   (at Assets/scripts/CubeScript.cs:14)

- но ведь в инспекторе они назначены?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У **[GetButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html)** надо указывать "Name", т.е. в данном случае это "Horizontal".

Для `Negative/Positive button` есть **[GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)**:

```
Input.GetKeyDown("w")
```

В нём же можно применять `KeyCode`:

```
 Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
```